# Python print statement adds spaces between arguments

Tags: python, spacing

I am coding a very basic hello program but I keep getting a space between the name and first exclamation mark that I am not seeing in the code. I have tried reformatting the string section a few different ways to concatenate the spacing out but I can't figure out what is causing the extra space. I've tried doing the exclamation mark alone, or part of the first of the next sentence, but it always has the extra space
after the variable `'name'`.

In contrast, the exclamation after variable age does not have the extra space, which is how I want both of them to look.

Here's the code and a screen shot - thanks you in advance.

```
name = input('Please enter your name: ')
age = input('Please enter your age: ')

print("Hello",name,"! You are",age,"nice to meet you!")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python print function automatically adds a space between arguments. You should concatenate (join) the strings together and then print them

```
print("a","b") # a b
print("a" + "b") # ab
```

In python, you can use "f-strings" which are a way to "template" the string. text inside of `{}` is treated like python, so you can put variables in there.

```
print(f"Hello {name}! You are {age} nice to meet you!")
```

f-strings are the best approach in python, but the first solution with "+" will work just fine for this use-case

Comment: ```+``` operator is the slowest for concatenation strings

Comment: I agree, however the reason I suggested this approach is because the OP is a beginner in python and I wanted to try and show what I would describe as "basic" techniques that would apply in almost every language. F-strings are python only and so if the OP wanted to use a different language they would not work. I'll update to show f-strings asweel

Comment: Thank you, this worked great! I tried it also with integers but received an error, do you have a recommendation for removing spaces with integers? Thanks again.

Comment: With integers, (and everything that isn't a string) you need to convert the int to a string first. Use `str(Varname)` to do that

Answer (score 1):

You can use `f-strings`. That is better and more pythonic:

```
print(f"Hello {name}! You are {age}. Nice to meet you!")
```

The `,` adds a space in python by default.

Answer (score 0):

also you can use `.format` like this:

```
name = input('Please enter your name: ')
age = input('Please enter your age: ')

print("Hello {}! You are {} nice to meet you!".format(name , age))
```

or:

```py
name = input('Please enter your name: ')
age = input('Please enter your age: ')

print("Hello {0}! You are {1} nice to meet you!".format(name , age))
```

second solution will be useful in cases like this:

```py
print("{0} is software engineer. also his son want to be programmer. {0} is good trainer".format("jackob"))
```

and how it works?
every thing in `.format(...)` have an index! for example, in `.format("jackob" , "sara")`, "jackob" index is **0** and "sara" index is **1**!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `print()` statement with C-style flags. It gives you precise control over how your string comes out.

```py
print('Hello %s! You are %d. Nice to meet you!' % (name, age))
```